# Unable to retrieve data from stored procedure in EF Core 7 with MariaDb

Tags: mysql, .net-core, stored-procedures, entity-framework-core, mariadb

I am using EF Core 7.0.9, Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 7.0.0 with MariaDb.

I am getting error when I try to call a stored procedure as mentioned below code `testResult2`.

The `testResult2` line

```
var testResult2 = await _dbContext.Address
                                  .FromSqlRaw("Call AddressSelectLatestId()")
                                  .Select(x => x.AddressId)
                                  .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

is throwing an error.

Can anyone help me to get the `addressId` without any issues?

```cs
using AutoMapper;
using KadaiS.Dal.Models;
using KadaiS.Domain.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Data;

namespace KadaiS.Dal.Repository
{
    public class AddressRepository : IAddressRepository
    {
        private readonly KadaiSDbContext _dbContext;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public AddressRepository(KadaiSDbContext kadaiSDbContext, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _dbContext = kadaiSDbContext;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }
        
        public async Task<int> InsertAddressAsync(Domain.Models.Address address)
        {
            try
            {
                var addressInsert = _mapper.Map<Domain.Models.Address, Models.Address>(address);
                var results = await _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlAsync($"Call AddressInsert({addressInsert.Street}, {addressInsert.City}, {addressInsert.Province}, {addressInsert.PostalCode})");

                if(results == 1)
                {
                    var testResult1 = await _dbContext.Address.FromSqlRaw("SELECT MAX(addressId) AS addressId FROM address").Select(x => x.AddressId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
                    var testResult2 = await _dbContext.Address.FromSqlRaw("Call AddressSelectLatestId()").Select(x => x.AddressId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
                }

                return 10;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the stored procedure **AddressSelectLatestId** sql

```sql
BEGIN
SELECT MAX(addressId) AS addressId FROM address;
END
```

The below mentioned text is the error

> MySqlConnector.MySqlException: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Call AddressSelectLatestId() ) AS `k`
> LIMIT 1' at line 3'

Comment: Could it possibly be a case sensitive thing ... `x.AddressId` => `x.addressId` ?
Seems to be ok checking with [this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qPQ41LTo) example.

Comment: @PaulT. No, I have already tried the case sensitive. Thank you for the suggestion :)

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say that due to this `.Select(x => x.AddressId)` EF core is generating SQL akin to `SELECT t1.AddressId FROM (Call AddressSelectLatestId()) AS t1` which is not valid syntax. You should be able to check the generated SQL when debugging though to confirm.

Comment: With that said, `FromSqlRaw` seems overkill here, why not simply `var testResult2 = await _dbContext.Address.MaxAsync(x => x.AddressId)`? Or if you are going to use Raw SQL throughout (which I have no issue with at all BTW) then you may be better off using a lighter weight ORM like Dapper * - other Micro ORMs are available but I can't vouch for them, Dapper is my to so I always plug that*

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use EF then you could just leverage the functionality of EF, so your method would be something like:

```
public async Task<int> InsertAddressAsync(Domain.Models.Address address)
{
    var addressInsert = _mapper.Map<Domain.Models.Address, Models.Address>(address);
    _dbContext.Addresses.Add(addressInsert);
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    var insertedId = addressInsert.AddressId;

    return 10; // No idea what this means but left it in from question
}
```

*N.B. I've removed the try/catch block because catching an exception then throwing it without doing anything is pointless*

Getting the latest address ID without doing an insert is as simple as:

```
_dbContext.Addresses.MaxAsync(x => x.AddressId);
```

But in the way you are using this it is not thread safe. If another thread inserts a different address after your insert is called, then the address ID you get back won't be the one you've inserted in your thread, which is presumably what you are trying to achieve?

As noted in a comment, if your going to use EF, then use EF and all its tools as above. They are there to make your life easier. If you're going down the route of writing your own SQL for each action in your DAL (which is by no means a bad thing, the generated SQL can be inefficient, so EF is great for writing small applications quickly, but large applications that scale may be better suited to this approach), then you may as well use something much more lightweight than EF. With Dapper for example you can call your SP as follows:

```
var addressId = await DbConnection.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<int>("AddressSelectLatestId", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

Although you would be better off returning the [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) from your insert stored procedure, and inserting and getting the ID in the same command. At a guess your SQL might be:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddressInsert(Street VARCHAR(50), City VARCHAR(50), Province VARCHAR(50), PostalCode VARCHAR(50), OUT AddressID INT)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO Address (Street, City, Province, PostalCode)
  VALUES (Street, City, Province, PostalCode); 

  SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO AddressID;
END
```

**[Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/osiTWHX_)**

Then your code might be something like:

```
var p = new DynamicParameters();
p.AddDynamicParams(new {addressInsert.Street, addressInsert.City, addressInsert.Province, addressInsert.PostalCode});
p.Add("AddressId", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
await connection.ExecuteAsync("InsertAddress", p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
var addressId = p.Get<int>("AddressID");
```

All of the above is possible with ExecuteSQLRaw and EF, but as I say if you're going to use EF you may as well take advantage of its functionality. If you're going to implement your own SQL, then ditch EF altogether since you're getting little or no advantage from it

Comment: I have gone through the Dapper functionalities, and it seems better. I have switched to Dapper. Thank you for the suggestion :)